# variable not updated outside if statement

Tags: java, swing

can someone explain me, why the variables “bookAvailable1” and “bookAvailable2”  don’t update after the button “borrowBook” or “returnBook” is clicked. I need to make a virtual library and I wont to update the stock  after the user borrowed or returned  a book.  What should I do?Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel panelChB, panelText;
    private JLabel title, bookTitle, bookTitle1;
    private JButton borrowBook, returnBook;
    private JCheckBox ch1, ch2;
    int bookAvailable1 = 3;
    int bookAvailable2 = 3;
    boolean haveBook1 = false;
    boolean haveBook2 = false;

    public MyFrame() {

        setSize(400, 150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Books");
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        panelChB = new JPanel();
        panelChB.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelChB, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        ch1 = new JCheckBox();
        ch2 = new JCheckBox();
        borrowBook = new JButton("BorrowBook");
        borrowBook.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (ch1.isSelected() || ch2.isSelected()) {
                    if (ch1.isSelected() && bookAvailable1 != 0) {
                        String infoMessage = "You borrowed \"Walk\"";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        bookAvailable1--;
                        haveBook1 = true;

                    }
                    if (ch2.isSelected() && bookAvailable2 != 0) {
                        String infoMessage = "You borrowed \"Red and Black\"";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        bookAvailable2--;
                        haveBook2 = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    String infoMessage = "No book selected";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                            "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

        });
        returnBook = new JButton("Return");
        returnBook.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (ch1.isSelected() || ch2.isSelected()) {
                    if (ch1.isSelected() && haveBook1 == true) {
                        String infoMessage = "Book \"Walk\" returned";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        bookAvailable1++;
                        haveBook1 = false;

                    }
                    if (ch2.isSelected() && haveBook2 == true) {

                        String infoMessage = "Book \"Red and Black\" returned";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        bookAvailable2++;
                        haveBook2 = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    String infoMessage = "No book selected";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                            "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }

            }

        });


        //System.out.println(available1);

        panelChB.add(ch1);
        panelChB.add(ch2);
        panelChB.add(borrowBook);
        panelChB.add(returnBook);


        //System.out.println(available1);
        panelText = new JPanel();
        panelText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelText, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        bookTitle = new JLabel("Walk - stock  " + bookAvailable1);
        bookTitle1 = new JLabel("Red and Black - stock  " + bookAvailable2);
        panelText.add(bookTitle);
        panelText.add(bookTitle1);

        add(panelChB, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(panelText, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: problem is you writes complete long code then find bug, while developing you should test each construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables *do* update, but that doesn't affect the labels on screen. By the time `bookAvailable1--;` has executed, the labels have already been initialized, and will not automagically change again.

Replace this:

```
bookTitle = new JLabel("Walk - stock  " + bookAvailable1);
bookTitle1 = new JLabel("Red and Black - stock  " + bookAvailable2);
```

with:

```
bookTitle = new JLabel();
bookTitle1 = new JLabel();
updateStockDisplay();
```

And add a new method:

```
private void updateStockDisplay() {
    bookTitle.setText("Walk - stock  " + bookAvailable1);
    bookTitle1.setText("Red and Black - stock  " + bookAvailable2);
}
```

Now, add a call to `updateStockDisplay();` at the end of each ActionListener for the borrow/return buttons, so that the labels are updated whenever the variables are changed.

Comment: Exactly this, you just need to make sure to update the text on the actual label rather than just the variable. The text will not automatically update so you need to call the setText method on your JLabel objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your haveBook2 and haveBook1 variable are false so It doesn't enter in the if section. Do the setVisible(true) at the end.